# Unexpected token error when parsing token stream with syn::parse2

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to parse a simple Rust file that looks like:

```rust
use std::result::Result;

fn init() {
}
```

In my `main` function, I read the file to a string, parse it, and then create a token stream which I then pass to `syn::parse2`. This returns an `unexpected token` error and I'm not sure why.

```rust
fn main() {
    if let Err(error) = try_main() {
        let _ = writeln!(io::stderr(), "{}", error);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

fn try_main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let filepath = PathBuf::from("./src/file-to-parse.rs");

    let code = fs::read_to_string(&filepath).map_err(Error::ReadFile)?;
    let syntax = syn::parse_file(&code).map_err({
        |error| Error::ParseFile {
            error,
            filepath,
            source_code: code,
        }
    })?;

    let token_stream = syntax.to_token_stream();
    let item: Result<Item, syn::Error> = syn::parse2(token_stream);

    match item {
        Ok(mut v) => {
            println!("success!");
        }
        Err(error) => {
            println!("{:?}", error.to_compile_error());
        }
    }
}
```

The full error it returns me is:

```rust
TokenStream [Ident { sym: compile_error, span: bytes(56..58) }, Punct { char: '!', spacing: Alone, span: bytes(56..58) }, Group { delimiter: Brace, stream: TokenStream [Literal { lit: "unexpected token", span: bytes(56..58) }], span: bytes(56..58) }]
```

What's even more confusing to me is that if I remove the import and keep the function, it parses fine. Also if I remove the function and keep the import it parses fine. It's only when I keep both of them that I get an error. Does this mean that it's an issue with the empty line?

Comment: Your input has 2 `Item`s. Do you want to parse only the first `Item` from the token stream?

Comment: Ah I never even noticed. Are you saying that it errors because it's attempting to treat the contents of the file as a single item which is incorrect since it's 2 separate items?

Comment: Yes. The error is that `syn` expects no further tokens after parsing the first `Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your program throws an error is because your input code has two items (`use` and `fn`) but you're attempting to parse the whole thing as a single `Item` with the `syn::parse2` line. This also explains why it works if you remove either the `use` or the `fn`.

If you want all the top level items in the code, you can already get that from the `File` struct that `syn::parse_file` returns:

```rust
fn main() {
    let code = "use std::result::Result;

fn init() {
}";

    let file = syn::parse_file(&code).unwrap();

    dbg!(file.items);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:9] file.items = [
    Use(
        ItemUse {
            attrs: [],
            vis: Inherited,
            use_token: Use,
            leading_colon: None,
            tree: Path(
                UsePath {
                    ident: Ident {
                        sym: std,
                        span: bytes(5..8),
                    },
                    colon2_token: Colon2,
                    tree: Path(
                        UsePath {
                            ident: Ident {
                                sym: result,
                                span: bytes(10..16),
                            },
                            colon2_token: Colon2,
                            tree: Name(
                                UseName {
                                    ident: Ident {
                                        sym: Result,
                                        span: bytes(18..24),
                                    },
                                },
                            ),
                        },
                    ),
                },
            ),
            semi_token: Semi,
        },
    ),
    Fn(
        ItemFn {
            attrs: [],
            vis: Inherited,
            sig: Signature {
                constness: None,
                asyncness: None,
                unsafety: None,
                abi: None,
                fn_token: Fn,
                ident: Ident {
                    sym: init,
                    span: bytes(30..34),
                },
                generics: Generics {
                    lt_token: None,
                    params: [],
                    gt_token: None,
                    where_clause: None,
                },
                paren_token: Paren,
                inputs: [],
                variadic: None,
                output: Default,
            },
            block: Block {
                brace_token: Brace,
                stmts: [],
            },
        },
    ),
]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4df57ca18d1521b8de6fb3059801e67)